# Xcode cannot detect device

Tags: xcode, ipad, version, device

I'm using xcode 4.6.

After I upgraded iPad from iOS 5.1 to 6.1, Xcode does not find device in schema.

Any solutions?

Comment: By schema do you mean organiser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure the following will work for you:

- Navigate to  `Window -> Organizer` and locate your device.
- Click on the "**Use for Development**" button.